# Для чего нужны конструкторы класса в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Я не могу понять для чего нужны конструкторы класса (**init** и т.д.)
Я понял что они нужны для создания объекта, но я не могу понять как его применять и когда он нужен...

Я умею писать только процедурные программы ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конструктор класса - это метод, который будет автоматически вызван при создании нового экземпляра данного класса. таким образом, если вы хотите, чтобы при создании экземпляра класса выполнялись некоторые действия (например, установка значений полей класса по-умолчанию или через переданные параметры и т.д.), то определяете в своем классе конструктор

Comment: _определяете в своем классе один или несколько конструкторов, различающихся количеством параметров_ - что вы имеете ввиду? В питоне нет перегрузки методов.

Comment: @mkkik, да, согласен, исправлю.